# Problem when installing QGIS 3.4.0 dependencies

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am trying to install QGIS from source code and I getting an error with SpatiaLite dependency. QGIS 3.4.0 requires SpatiaLite version >= 4.2.0.

I downloaded the version 5.0.0 from SpatiaLite, but when I try to configure QGIS running this command line code:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/qgis/3.4.1 -DSPATIALITE_LIBRARY=/opt/qgis/deps/spatialite/5.0/lib -DSPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/qgis/deps/spatialite/5.0/include ..
```

I get this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindSpatiaLite.cmake:75 (MESSAGE): Found SpatiaLite, but version is too old.  Requires at least version 4.2.0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: edit your post.

Comment: @Mr.AF, is everything okay now?